# Detect when a link is clicked in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

How do you detect when a link was clicked in a WKWebView?  I'm looking for the equivalent of this in a UIWebView.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {

    }
    return YES;
}
```

I tried this in the `WKNavigationDelegate` but I only ever get `WKNavigationTypeOther` for all requests even when clicking on links.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    if(navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated)
    {

    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Comment: What about `webView(_:didCommitNavigation:)`?

Comment: Just checked, and I get `WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated` after click on a link. Checked under iOS 9.1 and iOS 8.2.

Comment: I'm working with iOS 9.2.  I did some more testing and it seems it's links around images not working.  The documentation just says `A link with an href attribute was activated by the user.` for `WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated`.

Comment: Yep, when I click on an image inside of <a> tag, I get `WKNavigationTypeOther`. Looks like another one `WKWebView` bug to me.

Comment: Ok, thank you for verifying!  I will log a bug.  @Gasim, thanks for your comment too.  That approach does work instead.

Comment: @BerryBlue any update on this?

Comment: Hi guys, facing the same issue, getting type as other. Any solution would help pls.

Comment: It would help if any one share the html code for the link to show as TypeOther.

Comment: @BorysVerebskyi can you please share image inside of <a> tag html code which gives a WKTypeNavigationOther. I have tried but not finding when it comes. It would be really helpful.Much appreciated if you would help me.

Comment: @AkhilDad Did you done any workaround on this?Please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you can do in a `WkWebView` is the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let webView = WKWebView()
     self.view.addSubview(webView) // you need to also setup constraints here - I left out for clarity
     // Make sure you set the delegate, so you get the callback
     self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
}

 // WKWebViewNavigationDelegate
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
     guard let url = navigationAction.request.url, let scheme = url.scheme, scheme.contains("http") else {
            // This is not HTTP link - can be a local file or a mailto
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
     // This is a HTTP link
     open(url: url)
     decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

In this delegate method, you get the URL request that the `WKWebView` is trying to open. There you can check the attributes of the `URLRequest` and respond accordingly.

You can even write an extension for `URLRequest` that handles that logic, so you can reuse it.

```
extension URLRequest {
    var isHttpLink: Bool {
        return self.url?.scheme?.contains("http") ?? false
    }
}
```

Then you can change the long condition in the delegate method to:

```
 // WKWebViewNavigationDelegate
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
   guard navigationAction.request.isHttpLink else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }
   // ... handle url
```

Comment: Happy to hear that @iMRahib!