# Detect button click in WKWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

In my IOS Application I've created a **WKWebview** of a website that I'm not owning myself. So inside my:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
```

I've a couple of *.evaluateJavascript* that add data to textfields, removes elements on the website etc.

But I'm trying to add an *.evaluateJavascript* (Or other) that will recognize a button click on the website.

I've tried to add this by doing this code:

```
bookingView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('optional_button').onclick();") { (key, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            print("You tapped the button!")
        }
```

But that doesnt work. Everytime I open up the WebView the app prints out **"You tapped the button"** even if I didn't.

So, can I detect a button click with evaluateJavascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046978/detect-when-a-link-is-clicked-in-a-wkwebview

Comment: @user1374 I've tried that one.. Does not work :/

Comment: @Putte have you got the answer? if so kindly share here

Comment: @muthukumaresh I don’t.. i’m sorry. Dosent have the project anymore

Answer (score 7):

you can catch the url and react to it

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        guard let urlAsString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString.lowercased() else {
            return
        }

        if urlAsString.range(of: "the url that the button redirects the webpage to") != nil {
        // do something
        } 
     }
```

Comment: But the link might be different for each user. Since it's a booking system so I guess the booking ID will be different for each user... Hmm, any idea?

Comment: so you mean that the all url will be different or just the booking id in the params ?

Comment: Exactly. Since it's passing some sort of ID like. "URL/bid=17642911/"

Comment: look if  I got you right you can still use the method ..  if you have a url like this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265642
you can still catch this url :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I did for listening to button event click is to modify the html button by adding a href.

For example:

Adding a href to your button event "window.location.href = “iosapp://button1”;"

In your ios app

```
    -(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{

    if([navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"iosapp://button1"])
    {
        //Do whatever you need when this button is clicked
    }
    
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Vey simple solution:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click()", completionHandler: nil)
```

where replace 0 with the button index in the web page.

Comment: This is not a solution: it clicks on button instead of "detecting a button click", as question stands

Comment: This is not the solution to button click in webview